# Installing Python in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, python, windows-installer

My work PC has restrictions that stop me from adding programs to the start menu so when I try to install Python using the Python 2.6.5 Windows installer it can't complete as it tries to add a shortcut to my start menu.

Is there a way around this? I.e another way of installing without the need for a shortcut?
I've tried Python portable but as it doesn't add anything to the registry it can't be detected.

Comment: What is it you want anything in the registry?

Comment: I'm trying to install http://code.google.com/p/echo-nest-remix which checks which version of Python you have installed.

Comment: are you sure that the project is trying to read from the registry?  It looks like you might only need to have python somewhere in your path.  Can you try placing the portable Python in your user's path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your work PC has restrictions, this means your I.T. policies do not allow you to install programs on your PC. So what you ask here (correct me if I'm wrong) is to install a program on the sly. The same case is valid in our company, and when we really need to install a program to use within the scope of company, I.T. department evaluates the demand and installs the program after confirmation. So, if you are allowed to use Python at work, just tell I.T. to install it.

Comment: This was my last resort - our I.T dpt aren't the most speedy in the World! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!